# Lucene: What is the difference between Query and Filter

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Lucene query vs filter?

They both does similar things like termquery filters by term value, filter i guess is there for similar purpose.

When would you use filter and when query?

Just starting on lucene today so trying to clear concept

Answer (score 20):

Filter doesn't affect the computation of the score of the non-filtered documents.

For instance imagine the following docs:

```
1.
loc: "uk", "london"
text: "i live in london, "london is the best"

2.
loc: "london avenue", "london street", "london"
text: "I like the shop in london st."
```

now let's say you do the following query:

```
q=+loc:"london" +text:"london"
```

in this query the score of doc 2 is higher than that of doc 1 (because `loc` is calculated in the document score)

using a filter:

```
q=+text:"london" f=+loc:"london"
```

in this query the score of doc 1 is higher than that of doc 2.

Excuse the Solr style formatting but the overall notion is clear.

Other reasons for using filters are for caching purposes, filters are cached separately from queries so if you have a dynamic query with a static part it would make sense to filter by the static part. In this way the index traversal is limited to the subset of filtered docs.

Answer (score 9):

A `Query` can be passed to a `Searcher` to find documents. A `Filter` cannot; it can only modify the results produced by a `Query`.

Implementing a new `Query` type is fairly complicated, and requires an understanding of the relationship of Lucene internals like `Weight`, `Scorer`, and `Similarity`. A `Filter` implementation could be fairly simple, and not interact with the `IndexReader` at all.

Comment: Although what you're saying is correct in principal, Filters can be passed into Searchers as well but they work separately to queries

Comment: @Khash I'm not sure what you mean. If you are saying that `Filter` instances can be passed to a `Searcher` (or now just `IndexSearcher`), that's true, but only together with a `Query` or some other search criterion. They don't work by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

After you close a database, the filter's selection disappears. But when you close a Query, and open it again, it will still be there.

You can also create a Query using a Form. But you cannot use Filter in a Form.

Comment: What form are you talking about? Why can't a filter be used in such a form?